# During B2C login "Cant access your account?" to link to custom policy

Tags: azure

I've created a custom policy for B2C password reset to authenticate through mobile OTP and its working on jwt.ms testing.

Now I want to link this custom policy to "Cant access your account?" link available in B2C login screen.

I'm new in this so if its a stupid question, please help me with detials,

Thanks,
Sukesh

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off I think it is not a stupid question :)

As far as I know (and someone can correct me if I am wrong),
that link will always take you back to the app with an error.
It is intended that it is then the app's responsibility to redirect the user to the password reset.

If I had to guess why this is like this, I would say it is because a policy/user flow in B2C is basically a different identity provider.
Your app requested B2C to sign in the user with the "sign-in/sign-up" identity provider.
Fundamentally, B2C cannot sign in the user with some other policy now, as the resulting token would contain the wrong policy as the issuer.
Because of this design, the application (the relying party) has to send the user to the password reset policy from the start.

One thing I am really not sure about is if it is possible to create a custom sign-in/sign-up policy that would prompt the user with password reset steps inline within the same policy.
So the link etc. would not take the user to another policy but keep them in there and prompt for mobile OTP etc. and allow the user to reset their password and sign in.
A lot of things are possible with custom policies but this one I am not sure if it is possible :\